# I would like some suggestions for notating a matrix minor.

Tags: matrices, notation

I wish to show the steps in caculating the $ij$th minor of a matrix. I was thinking of writing $$\begin{vmatrix}
      de^{-x_1}+(1-x_1)e^{-2x_1} & (1-x_2)e^{-(x_1+x_2)} & \cdots & 
      (1-x_\ell)e^{-(x_1+x_\ell)}\\
      (1-x_1)e^{-(x_2+x_1)} & de^{-x_2} +(1-x_2)e^{-2x_2}& \cdots &
      (1-x_\ell)e^{-(x_2+x_\ell)}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      (1-x_1)e^{-(x_\ell+x_1)} &  (1-x_2)e^{-(x_\ell+x_2)} & \cdots & 
      de^{-x_\ell} +(1-x_\ell)e^{-2x_\ell}
    \end{vmatrix}_{ij}$$
to indicate that the $i$th row and $j$th column had been removed. I was wondering if there was an already existing convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two conventions are $M_i,_j$ and $M_{ij}$.

So,

$M_i,_j=\begin{vmatrix}
     de^{-x_1}+(1-x_1)e^{-2x_1} & (1-x_2)e^{-(x_1+x_2)} & \cdots & 
      (1-x_\ell)e^{-(x_1+x_\ell)}\\
      (1-x_1)e^{-(x_2+x_1)} & de^{-x_2} +(1-x_2)e^{-2x_2}& \cdots &
      (1-x_\ell)e^{-(x_2+x_\ell)}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      (1-x_1)e^{-(x_\ell+x_1)} &  (1-x_2)e^{-(x_\ell+x_2)} & \cdots & 
      de^{-x_\ell} +(1-x_\ell)e^{-2x_\ell}
    \end{vmatrix}$

If you wish to express it on the determinant, one suggestion is

$\begin{vmatrix}
      de^{-x_1}+(1-x_1)e^{-2x_1} & (1-x_2)e^{-(x_1+x_2)} & \cdots & 
      (1-x_\ell)e^{-(x_1+x_\ell)}\\
      (1-x_1)e^{-(x_2+x_1)} & de^{-x_2} +(1-x_2)e^{-2x_2}& \cdots &
      (1-x_\ell)e^{-(x_2+x_\ell)}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      (1-x_1)e^{-(x_\ell+x_1)} &  (1-x_2)e^{-(x_\ell+x_2)} & \cdots & 
      de^{-x_\ell} +(1-x_\ell)e^{-2x_\ell}
    \end{vmatrix}_{M_{i,j}}$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion